# Android - Pop two or more fragments but don't the top

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have the following scenario:

```
A(Bottom) -> B -> C -> D(Top) -back-> A
A(Bottom) -> B -> C -back-> B -back-> A
```

Once I'm on the top (D fragment) I want to pop B and C fragment. On this way when I press back from D I can to A.

I want to avoid the transitions on B and C when I back from D.
    A(Bottom) -> B -> C -> D(Top) -back-> C -back-> B -back-> A

**It is even posible?**

Comment: Do you want to go back from C to B if the user presses "Back" at C?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly, then when creating fragment D right before that you can try `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` which will look at your fragment stack and simply pop the last fragment. For this to work, you need to ensure that B and C are on the backstack so when creating those fragments you will need to call `addToBackStack(null)`. Now, when creating fragment D you can just `popBackStack()` twice and that will bring you back to A. I hope I am understanding your situation correctly.

Comment: But the thing is I don't want a see the transition D->C->B->A, I want to see D->A